# AngularJS ng-switch rendering order

Tags: angularjs

I have a question about ng-switch rendering order.

**Code(HTML):**

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
<button ng-click="v1 = !v1">toggle v1</button>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-switch on="v1">
            <th ng-switch-when="true">V1</th>
            <th ng-repeat="item in datas">{{item}}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Code(Javascript):**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.datas = ['A', 'B'];
}
```

I expected a result by the order :

V1 A B

But instead, the output shows ***ng-repeat items*** first, followed by ***ng-switch-when*** statement.

Why's that?

Is there an alternative solution to do such thing in my expected order?

[JSFiddle sample here.](http://jsfiddle.net/VeUAr/6/)

============================

## **Update (2014/04/02) :**

Here's the explanation for why ***ng-show*** is not an option.

I write a directive table like this :

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-show="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col.text}}</th>
        </td>
    </thead>
    <!-- body is ignored -->
</table>
```

The ***checkbox*** variable is for controlling whether the checkbox input should be showed.

This works fine until I apply ***JQuery ColResize***.

When the ***checkbox*** variable is false, the ***ng-show*** hides the first ***th*** element.

And somehow the hidden ***th*** element causes ***JQuery ColResize*** to malfunction.

Therefore ***ng-show*** is not suitable for this situation.

========================

## **Current Solution :**

My current solution is using ***ng-switch*** to separate two ***table*** element.

And use one variable to decide which ***table*** to draw.

Like this :

```
<div ng-switch on="checkbox">
    <table ng-switch-when="true">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col.text}}</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- body is ignored -->
    </table>
    <table ng-switch-default>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col.text}}</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- body is ignored -->
    </table>
</div>
```

Although this solve the problem, it is not a good solution.

But until I find an alternative solution.

I think I will have to settle for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-show` instead of `ng-switch` as shown in this modified [<kbd>**JSFIDDLE**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/D8v58/)

```
<tr>
    <th ng-show="v1">V1</th>
    <th ng-repeat="item in datas">{{item}}</th>
</tr>
```

ng-show applies style around the DOM element where the directive is used to show/hide respectively. In your case the header is compiled appropriately but will only be shown based on the condition that is provided to `ng-show`.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

"ng-show" will solve the "order" problem.

but in my specific case, "ng-show" will cause another problem.

Comment: That should have been mentioned in the question beforehand :). Elaborate what is the problem with using `ng-show`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll edit the question for the explanation.